# Dynamically inspecting css properties of an element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some web page that has a css that is a bit complicated for me, with lots of classes (it's from twitter bootstrap), and I want to see the properties of some element without having to analyse the css file (because that document is member of lots of classes and I find it complicated to look one by one for some properties).

So I open my webpage and ran in the console (in Chrome):

```
> tmp = $(".brand")
[
<a class=​"brand" id=​"appName" href=​"#">​LBY​</a>​, 
<a class=​"brand" id=​"about" href=​"/​about">​About​</a>​,
<a class=​"brand" id=​"index" href=​"/​">​Home​</a>​
]

> bb = tmp[0]
<a class=​"brand" id=​"appName" href=​"#">​LBY​</a>​

> bb.style.color
""
```

If I run `bb.style`, I get a list of css properties, but their values are mostly `""`, just like for the properties `color` above, while what I want is the actual value of the property. Is there some way to do that?

Comment: The elements tab in the developer panel of chrome will show you all the css styles currently on a given element and the files/lines where they are assigned. This should let you see what you are asking for without having to dig around in the entire css file and without playing around in the javascript.

Comment: dont you have `firebug`?

Comment: @Keeyai YES, I didn't know abot the elements tab, but it's so simple to check it. Thanks a lot. You can put this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Viscocent I don't have it, but I'll check it int the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created from comment on original post; doesn't answer the question as asked, but solved the problem.

The elements tab in the developer panel of chrome will show you all the css styles currently on a given element and the files/lines where they are assigned. This should let you see what you are asking for without having to dig around in the entire css file and without playing around in the javascript.